# What does = and the % part of %h2 in a template mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In RoR, what does the % part of %h2 mean? It's in a [html.haml file](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app/blob/master/app/views/conversations/index.html.haml). [Another file](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app/blob/master/app/views/conversations/_form.html.haml) has = signs in front of everything – what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a html.haml file. HAML is an ERB alternative. The `%` means it's an HTML tag (`<h2>` in this case), the `=` means Ruby code.

Here's an ERB translation:

```
<h1>Conversations</h1>
<h2>Inbox</h2>
  <ul><%= render mailbox.inbox %></ul>
<h2>Sentbox</h2>
  <ul><%= render mailbox.sentbox %></ul>
<h2>Trash</h2>
  <ul><%= render mailbox.trash %></ul>

<%= link_to 'Start Conversation', :new_conversation %>
```

Comment: Yeah, Just realized that. Thanks

Comment: `=` means "execute the Ruby code and output the result 'to HTML'". `-` means "execute this Ruby code (do not output result)".